# How to search for partial matches from a GIN index in a multi-word PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, gin-index

I have a GIN index in a Postgres database that I'm currently using to do full text search. So if a tsvector field contains the vectorized form of "mary had 4 little lambs" then I could search for "4 little lambs" with:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE text_index @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', '''4 little lambs'':*');
```

However, if I try to search for "4 lambs" with:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE text_index @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', '''4 lambs'':*');
```

this query returns no results.

Why isn't the index finding any partial matches? What's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Inspect the output of both your to_tsquery calls.  It is probably not doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `tsquery` is

```
SELECT to_tsquery('english', '''4 lambs'':*');

     to_tsquery     
════════════════════
 '4':* <-> 'lamb':*
(1 row)
```

That is a phrase where a word starting with "4" is right before a word starting with "lamb".  That won't match "4 little lambs".

If you want to search for texts that contain both "4" and "lamb" anywhere in the text, you should use

```
SELECT to_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', '4 & lambs');

  to_tsquery  
══════════════
 '4' & 'lamb'
(1 row)
```